# Scrollbar in Javafx in not scrolling

Tags: java, javafx, scrollbar, fxml, gridpane

I have a couple of line charts inside GridPane:

```java
@FXML
private GridPane LineChartVBox = new GridPane();
```

And this is my Scrollbar:

```java
ScrollBar sc = new ScrollBar();
sc.setMin(0);
sc.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
```

```java
hbox1.getChildren().addAll(LineChartVBox,sc);
sc.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
                        Number old_val, Number new_val) {
        LineChartVBox.setLayoutY(-new_val.doubleValue());
    }
});
```

I have a problem with the scrollbar because it does not do anything and I can not even see the end to it.
Here is the example of it:
[image: scrollbar_with]
[image]

Comment: Instead of using a ScrollBar, place your GridPane inside a [ScrollPane](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html).

Comment: I tried that too, but then it does not even give me the scrolling option...

Comment: Usually, the default behavior of a ScrollPane is not to show a scrollbar until it is needed.  Meaning, if your GridPane isn’t larger than the display area, no scrollbar will be visible.  This behavior can be altered by changing the [vbarPolicy](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#vbarPolicyProperty) of the ScrollPane.

Comment: A `HBox` assigns `layoutX` and `layoutY` of children during a layout pass. If you modify those properties for one of it's children, this simply triggers another layout pass undoing those modifications. You could use `translateY` instead to move the child relative to the position assigned by it's parent, but I strongly recommend using `ScrollPane`. If you put a child in a `HBox` with a min height that exceeds the scene size, this results in undefined behaviour. in this case `fillHeight` results in all children being resized to that height...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with VGR you should use a ScrollPane.
However its seems your ScrollBar is too height, you can try :

```
sc.maxHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
```

I copy-paste your code and your Listener is working, I had'nt tested with the same HBox and I suppose its also the HBox which fix the position of the GridPane.

You can try to `bind()` manually your ScrollBar position, but you can may be try to use `LineChartVBox.setTranslateY(-new_val.doubleValue());`